# mysql concat regexp word boundary and quote

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation, word-boundary

Here is my query

```
SELECT producer FROM producers WHERE producer REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', 'dell\'', '[[:>:]]')
```

I replaced mysql like with this to use word boundary from another example here. But now I am having a problem with escaped apostrophe, it doesn't find the dell' in the database even if there is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (select 'dell\'' as c) t where c regexp '[[:<:]]dell\'';        -- -> 1
select count(*) from (select 'dell\'' as c) t where c regexp '[[:<:]]dell\'[[:>:]]'; -- -> 0
```

So it's the trailing boundary requirement which fails. Which makes sense. Quoting from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html):

> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (`_`).

As `'` is not a word character, it cannot be the end of a word, hence `[[:>:]]` can't match.

Answer (score 0):

I created UDF and it solve the issue just give a call to a function you can set prefix, suffix and value depend upon your condition.

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pp`$$
CREATE  FUNCTION  `pp`(Slist varchar(100)) RETURNS char(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    Declare sregex varchar(100);
    SET slist  = 'G';
    return Concat('[[:<:]]',Slist,'[[:>:]]');
END;